# Passenger with two family names - Dominican Republic entry form

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, dominican-republic, tui

Travellers to the Dominican Republic are required to complete an [Electronic ticket](https://eticket.migracion.gob.do/?_gl=1*a56nb0*_ga*NzgzMjQ0ODc0LjE3MDgwMTY3OTU.*_ga_4K15NKSXKB*MTcwOTAzNTQyNS4yLjAuMTcwOTAzNTQyNS42MC4wLjA) for entry and exit prior to arrival.

I’m the lead passenger (UK citizen/resident) travelling with my partner (DR visa national, currently in UK on long-term Visitor visa). As I understand it, we complete one e-ticket form covering both of us, which I have done.

I have two first names and one family name. My partner has one first name and two family names. When I input them as:
‘Name1 Name2’ with a space between them, I can see his full name in the system but only his first name appears on the QR confirmation, which means it does not match his passport. As an example:

- Jane Mary Smith
- Juan

I suspect putting a space between the two family names might be the problem, however that is how they appear in his passport.

Does anyone know how to enter two family names so that both appear in the confirmation?

Note: I have emailed the e-ticket support team but had no reply so far.

Comment: Where exactly do you not see the full name? The QR Code only contains an UUID.

Comment: @jcaron The passenger names, nationalities and passport numbers are shown below the QR code in the pdf confirmation. My full name is shown correctly, that of my partner only shows his first name.

Comment: When you say "first name", do you mean the first of his family names, or his given name? They may have planned this for people from a family who (often, but definitely not always) have the same surname(s), so they dispensed with showing the surname(s) on each confirmation. But my guess is that this is only for your own information: the QR Code contains a UUID which, I suppose, allows them to retrieve the full file.

Comment: @jcaron I mean his given name. As is the practice in many Hispanic American countries, including the DR, his two last names (‘surnames’) are composed of the [first surname of each parent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_customs_of_Hispanic_America). I might try a resubmit replacing the space between the two names by ‘_’ although my concern about matching his passport remains. He normally needs a visa to enter DR but can do so on the basis of his UK visa, I’m not sure how familiar a British tour operator airline will be with that so I’m obviously keen to get the paperwork watertight :-)

Comment: I tried with a dash and it says no. I don’t think the issue is with his two surnames but with the fact he’s in the same file as you. You can try putting him first (will probably shift the problem to you) or to a separate file.

Comment: @jcaron Ok thanks, I’ll try your suggestions and report back :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

No reply from the e-ticket support team after three days (it may have disappeared into my junk mail filter). Meantime I’ve spoken to the Tui Help team three times, getting a slightly different response each time.

- First call: agent gave me the PNR (for some reason this doesn’t seem to be included in the booking confirmation and the DR e-ticket system did not accept the booking reference) and said to complete one e-ticket for both passengers with myself as the lead.
- Second call: queried the ‘missing’ second passenger data. After referring to a colleague, the agent said because of the second traveller’s nationality I needed to complete two *separate* e-ticket forms. I did not do this as to me it makes no sense to portray the second passenger as the lead when he clearly is not.
- Third call: after I explained my concern about the ‘missing’ data, the agent stated categorically that it does not matter - as long as the lead passenger’s details are correct, it's sufficient for the QR confirmation form to show only the second passenger’s first name (plus nationality and passport number).

I have a note of the date/time of the call and the agent’s name in case of challenge at check-in and will update my answer if we encounter any problems.

Update: the check-in agent didn’t even ask to see the e-ticket QR code (despite dire warnings about the risk of check-in delay / denial of boarding  from failure to complete the form in comms from the travel company).